# Uncaught ReferenceError: Tibia is not defined

Tags: javascript, promise

When I'm using my ES6 class `Tibia` in my app.js file, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Tibia is not defined.

app.js file:

```
const tibia = new Tibia;

document.getElementById('search-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    const searchedCharacter = document.getElementById('searchCharacter').value;
    tibia.getCharacter(searchedCharacter); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

class file:

```
class Tibia {
    async getCharacter(char) {
        const characterResponse = await 
        fetch(`https://api.tibiadata.com/v2/characters/${char}.json`);

        const character = await characterResponse.json();

        return {
            character
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't linked the files together properly. Check your imports and exports. You should also give your `new` statements argument lists, even if empty

Comment: What do you mean by "class file"? In which environment are you running them? How do you import them?

Comment: You need to `import` your class if it's in another file to use it. Do you have that anywhere, it's not in the code you've shown?

Comment: @CertainPerformance "*You should also give your new statements argument lists, even if empty*" - why that?

Comment: @Bergi Isn't that what linters always recommend? Constructor invocations, being essentially special function calls, should be accompanied by `()`, even if a script can be parsed without them?

Comment: @CertainPerformance My linter doesn't. I don't think there are any readability or ambiguity difficulties.

Comment: Well, i did everything like id Brad Traversy's course. He didn't import/export any classes there. He just wrote code in different files and everything worked for him.

Comment: @D.Wasilewski How did he run the files? Did you just use `<script src="…">` tags in a html file? What did you do?

Comment: @Bergi, exactly. I just used <script src="..."> in html

Comment: @D.Wasilewski Did you import them in the right order? Did you get the path right? Please post your html.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for helping! Order of imports was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should export your `Tibia` class, like that in a class file:

```
export { Tibia };
```

And you should import your `Tibia` class in `app.js`, like that:

```
import { Tibia } from 'path-to-file.js';
```

Or like that:

```
export default Tibia;
```

And:

```
import Tibia from 'path-to-file.js';
```

Comment: OP doesn't use ES6 modules, so this is unlikely to help